# What is Model–View–Whatever (MV*) ? How it works in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

What is this Model–View–Whatever (MV*) ?

How it will work in angularjs ? Can someone explain briefly?

Comment: @suzo my question is completely different from that. this between MVC and   MV*

Comment: Sorry about that, removed my comment.

Comment: @suzo thats not a problem

Comment: This quora post might help https://www.quora.com/What-is-MVW-Model-View-Whatever-How-is-it-different-from-MVC

Comment: @suzo its nice link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Model-View-Whatever** paradigm is a term used to indicate the capability of the framework being used to give the option to choose from MVC or MVVM approaches. Like in Angular.js.

The Angular team wants you to use “whatever” of the following systems work for you. you can use Model View Controller, Model View Adapter, Model-View-ViewModel etc

[visit here for more info](https://www.quora.com/What-is-MVW-Model-View-Whatever-How-is-it-different-from-MVC)